# Having trouble creating a function that takes one argument, and returns a result of adding odd numbers between 1 and argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So far I have this...

```
  def sumOfOdds(n):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
        result = result + i
        print(result)
```

This gives me the sum, but it also prints all the numbers that come before it. I just need the sum, not the rest of the values.

Comment: Umm, by writing appropriate code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop and `range()` with 2 as `step`

```
sum = 0
max = 11
for i in range(1, max, 2): # not including max
    sum += i
print sum

#out:25 (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
result = [i for i in xrange(0, arg) if i % 2 == 0]
```

maybe somehow like this

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 10
sum(filter(lambda x: x%2, xrange(0, num)))

# Output: 25
```